# How to install and use Lottie/JSON animation code for WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, lottie

This is my first time programming for windows platforms and I'm trying to do a UI/UX fluent and modern app. So, I've heard that the best over-platform way to do it is with vector animation and therefor with bodymotion and lottie, because the good design, soft movement and I could get the animations from a professional designer.

The problem is that I tried to install multiple times the nuget package for lottie animations in my WPF project as I read in the official web: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/communitytoolkit/animations/lottie-scenarios/getting_started_json and I only obtained errors related to the framework version:

- `Could not install package 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

Initially I thought that the problem was the .NET framework so I migrate the project to .NET Core. And then I've tried again and got:

- `Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie 7.0.0-preview4 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie 7.0.0-preview4 supports: uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)`
- `Microsoft.UI.Xaml nuget package requires TargetPlatformMinVersion >= 10.0.15063.0 (current project is -1)`

Investigating I understood that the packages were created for UWP and not for WPF. Consequently I investigate about XAML Islands, that brings UWP functions to WPF, but they only work with xaml map, I could't use to install nuget packages.

I don't find more information and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I wonder:

1. What alternatives I have to add some soft and good looking animated buttons? Preferably with a complete documentation
2. There is a way to use lottie in WPF? Or it is unnecessarily complicate?
3. Which is the traditional way to animate and work with natively in WP?

Comment: Did you install `LottieSharp` in the NuGet for your WPF project? You can test the project from [OmidID Github](https://github.com/ascora/LottieSharp).

Comment: Okay, I'll try it today and telling you. Thanks